# PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, ssh, cron, chmod

I'm just trying to create a file to be run from a cron job but however I'm getting the below error log.

`PHP Warning:  require(../app/src/app.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/mosto.in/manual/gateway.php on line 4
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../app/src/app.class.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/mydomain.in/manual/gateway.php on line 4`

**My gateway.php file**

`set_time_limit(0);
require('../app/src/app.class.php');`

I'm confused if I'm running the same file on my ssh server using the below path the file not generating any errors & working very fine.

`*cd /var/www/mosto.in/manual/
*php gateway.php`

**Crontab**

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mosto.in/manual/gateway.php > /var/log/gateway.log 2>&1
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that the working directory for the cron daemon is not the same as when you execute it manually. See if this works:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/mosto.in/manual/ && /usr/bin/php gateway.php > /var/log/gateway.log 2>&1
```

If it does, I'd consider moving the `cd` and `php` call into a script file and calling that from your crontab instead - but that might just be me :p

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a script through shell / crontab, the best way to call required files are to give absolute paths in the require() or require_once() statements.

```
require('/var/www/mosto.in/app/src/app.class.php');
```

Hope this will work for you.